App de radio en Android se detiene al bloquear el celular y al pasar a segundo plano
Estoy desarrollando una app de radio en Android Studio y me estoy encontrando con un problema persistente. Cuando el usuario bloquea el celular o la aplicación pasa a segundo plano, la transmisión de la radio se detiene después de aproximadamente un minuto. Esto sucede tanto en dispositivos con versiones recientes de Android como en versiones más antiguas.
Detalles de la implementación:
Estoy utilizando un Service para manejar la reproducción de la radio en segundo plano.
He implementado un MediaPlayer para la transmisión de la radio.
He añadido los permisos necesarios en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml (WAKE_LOCK, INTERNET, etc.).
public class RadioService extends Service implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private static final String STREAM_URL = "https://radiolatina.info/9930/stream";
    private static final String TAG = "RadioService"; // Define una etiqueta para los registros de depuración
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Servicio creado");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        if (wifiLock != null && wifiLock.isHeld()) {
            wifiLock.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared: Reproducción iniciada");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        // Handle audio focus changes if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

Lo que he intentado:
Utilizar startForeground para convertir el servicio en un servicio en primer plano.
Añadir un WakeLock para evitar que el dispositivo entre en modo de suspensión.
Probar diferentes configuraciones en el manifest para asegurar que el servicio se mantenga activo.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia. ¡Gracias de antemano!
